# Getting path of working directory

Tags: c#

I need to access working directory from code in `C#` in `MSVS 2013` like:

`C:\SomePath\Visual\NameOfTheProject\`

In `java` we can access it `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Does `C#` have equivalent?

@update

Problem is that I need to search folder `X` for implementations of some interface. App will be executed on different machines, so I should have a path which will always navigate me to folder `X`

@update2

I need to look for the folder with `dlls` which is named `X` in the folder where I execute the app (so my assembly).

Comment: Do either of: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d8798db-32eb-4886-9531-31b3decba018/how-can-i-get-the-current-working-directory-at-runtime?forum=csharplanguage

help?

Comment: Do you want the current directory of your executable?

Comment: Well thing is I need to search my directory for implementation of some interface in dll's file. I assume current directory will be nice.

Comment: Regarding the update: What is folder `X`? Is it the folder where the application is installed? Or the directory from where it was invoked?

Comment: What @AndersAbel is asking, do you mean the folder where the application is (The actual .exe), or where it is opened from (Ex: A shortcut on the desktop)

Comment: @AndersAbel I'm on a project stage. Project path `C:/Project/` and it contains folders `X` so `(C:/Project/X)` and inside there is some `dll's` which I need to analyze.
@Cyral actual.exe file

Comment: @krzakov I've updated my answer with a method to get where the exe is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the absolute path to the executable file (And not where it was executed from, if it was through a shortcut) you can use:

[`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.executablepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Needs to be using Windows Forms)

*or*

`System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);`

Both will return the directory that your executable is found in.

To get the path of another folder within your executable's directory, you can use this:

```
Path.Combine(path, "X");
```

Where `path` is any of the above examples.

Answer (score 2):

[`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) will return the current working directory of the process. That is the equivalent of the `"user.dir"` property in Java.

To get the directory of the exe (or actually, the entry assembly, which is normally the exe), use `Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)`

- [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`Assembly.Location`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.location%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: While this answer is correct in itself, I am not convinced that is what the OP is looking for, at least not any more after the explanatory comment of what this is for.

Comment: Checking. I need path, where I execute the app .

Comment: You're right. I looked up the `"user.dir"` property to be sure I presented the exact equivalent, but it might not be what OP wants.